# C# restore database with microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo 5(access denied)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016, smo

I am trying to restore a db with `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` but I keep getting access denied errors.

I have set up the service user for the instance (`MSSQL$LOCAL2016`) with full access rights to the folder.

The folder is the default folder for the instance (although the same cannot be said when I move to production).

I create the folders within C#

```
rstDatabase.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

fails with the error:

> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Database\Rates.setuptest\Data'.
>   File 'RateUploader' cannot be restored to 'C:\Database\Rates.setuptest\Data'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Database\Rates.setuptest\Logs'.
>   File 'RateUploader_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Database\Rates.setuptest\Logs'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I have changed the folder permissions even so far as to allow 'everyone' full access

I have changed the service login to local service and allowed access to local directory

I am fresh out of ideas

Here is the code, but it's pretty standard

```
    public static IEnumerable<RestoreDatabaseResponse> RestoreDatabase(String databaseName)
    {
        var eventQueue = new Queue<RestoreDatabaseResponse>();
        var counter = 0;

        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder stringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["adminSqlAccess"].ConnectionString);

        string serverName = stringBuilder.Server, userName = stringBuilder.UserID, password = stringBuilder.Password, 
            pFileLocation = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbPath"], databaseName, "Data"), 
            lFileLocation = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbPath"], databaseName, "Logs"),
            bakFileLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bakDbPath"];

        //permisions are propagating
        if (!Directory.Exists(pFileLocation))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pFileLocation);
        if (!Directory.Exists(lFileLocation))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(lFileLocation);

        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
        Restore rstDatabase = new Restore();

        //recently added events for reporting.  Still fails without these two
        rstDatabase.Complete += (sender, args) =>
        {
            eventQueue.Enqueue(new RestoreDatabaseResponse
            {
                Command = $"Restore {databaseName}",
                Status = ResponseStatus.Success,
                Detail = "Complete",
                Index = counter++,
                PercentComplete = 100
            });
        };

        rstDatabase.PercentComplete += (sender, args) =>
        {
            eventQueue.Enqueue(new RestoreDatabaseResponse
            {
                Command = $"Restore {databaseName}",
                Status = ResponseStatus.PartialSuccess,
                Detail = "Running",
                Index = counter++,
                PercentComplete = args.Percent
            });
        };

        rstDatabase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        rstDatabase.Database = $"Rates.{databaseName}";

        // I even tried skipping this step.  Still error
        rstDatabase.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("RateUploader", pFileLocation));
        rstDatabase.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("RateUploader_log", lFileLocation));

        BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(bakFileLocation, DeviceType.File);
        rstDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
        rstDatabase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        RestoreDatabaseResponse errorResponse = null;

        try
        {
            rstDatabase.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            errorResponse = new RestoreDatabaseResponse
            {
                Command = $"Restore {databaseName}",
                Status = ResponseStatus.Failure,
                Detail = exception,
                Index = counter++,
                PercentComplete = 0
            };
        }

        if (errorResponse != null)
        {
            yield return errorResponse;
            yield break;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (!eventQueue.Any())
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            else
            {
                var e = eventQueue.Dequeue();
                yield return e;

                if(e.Status== ResponseStatus.Success)
                    yield break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh for Pete's sake!

I omitted the filename from the relocate paths >_<

To be fair, "move" does imply moving from one folder to another, also the error message is identical to the permission issues most people seem to have hit

Comment: Glad you figured it out. The move error is applicable as it might be the actual intent, the engine has no way of knowing. That said, security error messages returned to users generally tend to be vague to avoid helping a malicious user. Error logs (secured by default) usually have more details.